# Proof Writing Help: $P_UT=TP_U \Leftrightarrow U$ and $U^{\perp}$ are $T$-Invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-verification, orthogonality

I'm studying linear algebra using Axler's book on my own and this is also my first rigorous encounter with proofs would greatly appreciate suggestions to improve the writing of the first part of my proof (i.e. U is T-invariant => $P_UT=TP_U$).

I'd appreciate suggestions to:

1. Reduce unnecessary verbiage and make my proofs more concise and readable
2. Remove any possible logical flaws

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Prove that $U$ and $U^\perp$ are invariant under $T$ if and only if $P_UT = TP_U$.

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. By Theorem 6.32, $V = U \oplus U^\perp$.

Suppose $U$ and $U^\perp$ are invariant under $T$. Let $v \in V$. By direct sum decomposition, we can write $v = u + w$ where $u \in U$ and $w \in U^\perp$. 
Then, $P_UTv=P_UT(u+w)=P_UTu+P_UTw$. Since $Tu \in U$, we have $P_UTu=Tu$. Since $Tw \in U^\perp$, we have $P_UTw=0$. Therefore, $P_UTu+P_UTw = 
Tu+P_UTw=Tu$. Since $u \in U$, $u=P_Uu$. Therefore, $Tu=TP_Uu$. Since $w \in U^\perp$, $P_Uw = 0$ and so $T0=TP_Uw=0$.  So $P_UTv=Tu=Tu+0=TP_Uu+TP_Uw=
TP_U(u+w)=TP_Uv$. Therefore, $PT_Uv=TP_Uv$ as we needed to show.

Second part:

Now suppose $P_UT=TP_U$. Let $u \in U$ and $w \in U^\perp$. By definition of projection, $P_Uu=u$ and $P_Uw=0$. We have $P_UTu=TP_Uu=Tu$. By definition
of projection $P_UTu \in U$. $Tu \in U$ and therefore $U$ is T-invariant. By definition of projection, $P_Uw=0$. We have $TP_Uw=T0=0=P_UTw$. Since $P_UTw=0$,
we know that $Tw \in U^\perp$ and therefore $U^\perp$ is also T-invariant.

Thanks again!

Comment: You supposed that $U^\bot$ is also $T$-invariant, but you were only given that $U$ is $T$-invariant.

Comment: I phrased the question incorrectly. I will change that! Thanks! I don't think this statement is valid if we don't have that $U^\perp$ is T-invariant.

Comment: How is $P_U$ defined? If it is the projection derived from the direct sum decomposition, i.e. $P_U(v)=P_U(u+w)=u$, then the second half of your proof can be shortened considerably, as you know by definition of the projection that $u=P_Uv$.

Comment: You did not prove the reverse implication.

Comment: Just copied the reverse implication here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not bad at all.  However, you only proved half the statement!  You need to prove that if $P_UT=TP_U$, then $U$ and $U^\perp$ are $T$-invariant.

Remember that you are writing for an audience (that's us!), and that your job is to communicate with us as clearly as possible while being succinct.  The long string of equalities is a bit much in the second to last sentence of your proof.  You can significantly cut down on the wordage and do most of the grunt work earlier in your proof.  While everything you have written down is right, there is no clear flow to your proof.  You calculate a bunch of quantities and then show how they give the result at the end.  I would structure your proof by saying something like, "first, we find $P_UTv$", and then do the related calculations to conclude $P_UTv=Tu$ (easy!).  Then tell us, "now, we will find $TP_Uv$" and conclude after some more calculations that $TP_Uv = Tu$ (also really easy!)  You've shown that $P_UTv$ and $TP_Uv$ are equal to the same thing, so you can point that out to us, and then you're done with that direction of the proof!

Comment: I just added the other half of the statement. Forgot to copy it from MikTeX. These suggestions are good, especially doing the grunt work earlier in the proof and improving the logical flow. This is helpful and hopefully knowledge of proof writing is transferable to better communication in the non-mathematical professional world.